# WCF Download File Aborted By Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, download, httpcontext

I have the following code for downloading large files. It reads from a filestream and writes to the Response.Outputstream.

It seems to be working, i.e., the file appears to dowload (actually it seems to be downloading more, weirdly) but it fails at the end. Chrome gives a "Network error" and IE shows "(Aborted)"

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/f/{key}", Method = "GET")]
    public void LargeFileDownload(string key)
    {
        var identifier = PublicIdentifier.FromString(key, true);
        if (identifier.Type == PublicIdentifier.IdentifierType.DocumentDownload)
        {
            Document doc = Business.Documents.GetById(Application.SystemUser, identifier.Id);

            string tempName = Path.GetTempPath() + doc.OriginalFileName;

            int bufferSize = 8192;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long fileSize = fstream.Length;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = doc.ContentType;

            string contentDisposition = string.Format("{0};filename={1}{2}", "attachment", doc.Name.Replace(" ", "_"), Path.GetExtension(doc.OriginalFileName));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = doc.ContentType;
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fstream != null)
                    fstream.Close();

                //File.Delete(tempName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Updated code:-

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/f/{key}", Method = "GET")]
    public void LargeFileDownload(string key)
    {
        var identifier = PublicIdentifier.FromString(key, true);
        if (identifier.Type == PublicIdentifier.IdentifierType.DocumentDownload)
        {
            Document doc = Business.Documents.GetById(Application.SystemUser, identifier.Id);

            string tempName = Path.GetTempPath() + doc.OriginalFileName;

            int bufferSize = 8192;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long fileSize = fstream.Length;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            string contentDisposition = string.Format("{0};filename={1}{2}", "attachment", doc.Name.Replace(" ", "_"), Path.GetExtension(doc.OriginalFileName));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fstream != null)
                    fstream.Close();

                //File.Delete(tempName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Fiddler raw:-

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 11:53:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 12:53:09.099

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 13,912,938 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `Content-Length` correctly and the browser assumes that value is true. But because of this bug you're sending more data (which is garbage):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

This should not be `bufferSize` but `bytesRead`. This leads to a protocol error causing the browser to abort its processing.

The copy loop should probably be replaced by a call to `TransmitFile`, or at least by `Stream.Copy`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I'm still getting the same error, though, after making that change. I also tried TransmitFile but I'm working with large files and that gives an OutOfMemory exception. I tried fstream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream) but that caused a "server error" (500)

Comment: Post the updated code please. @nouns Also, TransmitFile should not out of memory. Again, post code. "but that caused a "server error" (500)" is very unspecific information! Please post the full exception.

Comment: Okay, comparing the downloaded file (IE lets me copy out the temp file) with the server-side original in a hex editor, I can see that Unicode replacement characters are getting inserted. That would account for the extra length. Why am I getting those, though? It's supposed to be a binary file (actually MP4 videos). Wrong kind of input file stream? Setting missing from the response stream?

Comment: Posted updated code. As I say, I think the issue is due to a Unicode conversion.

Comment: Looks pretty good. What's the content type being sent? Try using Fiddler to see what actually goes over the write. Validate the Content-Length and Content-Type header as well as the data being sent is not affected by the Unicode problem. Fiddler also warns about protocol violations. @nouns

Comment: I'm setting the content-type to "application/octet-stream" in code (now hard-coded). The buffer doesn't contain unicode chars after it's been read in. I'll edit the post above to show the Fiddler output.

Comment: `Server returned 13,912,938 bytes.` is that the correct number of bytes? One idea would be this: Maybe after your code other code runs. Maybe WCF appends some other content. Maybe WCF tries to generate a response by itself. Try adding Response.End() to make sure nothing is appended. @nouns